# What punishment do the parents get upon abusing their children

Tags: quran

I'll come straight to the point.
As a child who's abused by her father mentally and physically I really really want to know what punishment he deserves, (or if he doesn't deserve punishment at all) I'm sorry if this makes you uncomfortable upon hearing that a daughter wants her father to get punished by Allah (s) but I don't think I can recover from the trauma he has given me. Its so suffocating being around him. I hate to the point where I instantly get annoyed when I see his face.
So can I please have a proper answer regarding my question

Comment: If your father did something wrong then he may be punished by Allah. 'How' is known by Allah alone.

Comment: There are evidences that a guardian shall not hit their children so as to leave a mark on the latter body's otherwise they will be questioned on this as a form of sin on day of resurrection.